# Django - django-autocomplet-light fields does not display with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-autocomplete-light

dal fields of my app are working perfectly when I use "python manage.py runserver" but when I try to run my app with gunicorn the dal fields are empty (as if I didn't put form.media in my template ...). Except for dal field there is no problems.
Is there something to change in the code for dal to work with gunicorn? 
My code is on github (https://github.com/jmcrowet/limonada/blob/master/limonada/forcefields/forms.py)

Comment: Where are these files served from when running gunicorn? You probably need to collectstatic

Comment: The files are in my static_url and the location is specified in the nginx configuration file. My js files are normally used ...